# HTML not showing up on Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I am trying to return a PHP page via AJAX and it always loads in Chrome. In Firefox, it loads about 5% of the time, the other times it loads with nothing with no JS/PHP errors. I'm just echoing straight html back without CSS.

Here is my Ajax:

```
if(geo_position_js.init()){
            geo_position_js.getCurrentPosition(displayPosition,error_callback,{enableHighAccuracy:true,options:5000});
        }
        else{
            alert("Functionality not available");
        }

        function error_callback(p)
        {
            alert('error='+p.message);
        }       

    function displayPosition(loc) {
        var mylat = loc.coords.latitude;
        var mylong = loc.coords.longitude;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "distancetest.php",
            data: "long="+mylong+"&lat="+mylat,
            success: function(html2){
                $('#locationinfo').html(html2);
                console.log(html);
           }
        });

    }
```

My PHP is basically doing this a couple times:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_geo WHERE cat_id=1";
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<h2>Restaurants</h2>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if($row['lat'] != ''){
            $distance = distance($_POST['lat'], $_POST['long'], $row['lat'], $row['lng'], "k");
            if($distance < 2000){
                $attractions[] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'address' => $row['address'], 'distance' => $distance);
            }
        }
    }
    $attractions = array_sort($attractions,'distance');
    $attractions = array_values($attractions);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        if(isset($attractions[$i]['distance'])){
            echo 'You are '.$attractions[$i]['distance'].'km away from '.$attractions[$i]['name'].' at '.$attractions[$i]['address'].'<br/>';
        }
    }
```

Works in some browsers, but displays nothing in others. Any ideas?

UPDATE: Turns out this is a problem with geolocation in Firefox. It fails at getting the position but doesn't come back to the error_callback function. Live example is here: http://adamzwakk.com/geolocate/

Comment: When it "returns nothing", are you certain that the AJAX request is actually going out?

Comment: Use something like HTTPFox or Firebug to monitor the browser<->server communications. See what's happening during those pauses. Without any kind of diagnostics info, it'd be pretty much impossible to figure this out.

Comment: It doesn't look like the PHP page is loading at all sometimes in Firefox randomly. Using POST and GET makes no difference either.

Comment: Will also fail in several other browsers:  http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/02/geolocation-in-html5-browser-and-device-support/  This lack of support would render it an unsupported feature to many of the clients I work with.

Comment: I am using Firefox 3.6 and 4.0 beta and the bug still occurs on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your browser supports what you are doing?

Try this:
http://html5demos.com/geo

You can also download wireshark and check the information sent by you and returned from the server.

It is also good practice to put blank php page (just echo a random string) in the same directory where you want to generate your php and see if it is working. On Windows based servers it is a common problem that PHP can be set to work in specific directories, and because of mis-installing can fail in others.
Every browser handles errors and warning messages differently, so if it works in chrome, it does not mean it works on everything else. Have you tried with Safari and Opera?

Comment: You can also download wireshark and check the information sent by you and returned from the server. - firebug shows it too

Answer (score 0):

I opened up FireBug and your clicked on the link to find my address. It returned a load of links saying "undefined". In FireBug it shows that your script is returning this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <geoData>
    <restaurants>
    </place>
    </restaurants>
    <accommodations>
    </accommodations>
    <things>
    </things>
  </geoData>
```

I indented it to make it look nicer. It appears your application is returning nothing in the XML. You are also closing a  tag which isn't open!

Answer (score 0):

**Use console.log() with caution**

Using console.log() in your javascript code throws an exception when firebug is disabled or not installed. (95% of the time?)
I wrote a little wrapper function "dump(var)" [dump.js](https://github.com/bfanger/sledgehammer_core/blob/master/public/javascripts/dump.js) that checks if firebug is enabled so it's also safe to use in production code.

PS:
I noticed:

```
 success: function(html2){
   $('#locationinfo').html(html2);
   console.log(html);
 }
```

Is the `html` variable defined earlier or did you mean `html2`.